# When I edit .bashrc in Ubuntu 20.04, it does not ask me to save anymore

Tags: command-line, bash, python, bashrc

I'm not sure what happened but when I
`sudo nano ~/.bashrc` to add a couple of exports

```
#spotify
export SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
export SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

before it would ask me something about saving changes, I'd ctrl-x to exit and then it would ask me if I wanted to save changes to which I'd answer 'yes' and ctrl-X to exit but now it skips this and goes right back to

```
(spotifydl) nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:/media/nobu/NTFSUbuWin/downloadsUbu$
```

where spotifydl is the activated conda environment where I have the pip package installed.
`https://github.com/SathyaBhat/spotify-dl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md`

Why is Ubuntu skipping the ctrl-X save step after editing `.bashrc` now?
doing `source ~/.bashrc` seems to have no effect now (because of this?)

Edit as directed by @sudodus here is the output.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobu nobu 5540 Oct 30 11:10 /home/nobu/.bashrc
```

I tried

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

The exports are there but again I am not prompted to save.

Comment: Please run `ls -l ~/.bashrc` and edit the original question to show the output from the command. It will tell us if you have created problems with ownership because you use `sudo` when you should not. It is a file that should belong to your normal user ID. - Try with `nano ~/.bashrc`

Comment: The ownership and permissions are OK. The problem is somewhere else. But you do remember, that if you did not change anything, `nano` knows that, and exits without saving? So try again with `nano ~/.bashrc` and add something harmless, try to save it, and check what happens.

Comment: It would be interesting to try `gedit ~/.bashrc` and see if that allows you to save changes.

Comment: I tried `gedit ~/.bashrc` and I clicked save, closed the editor, did `source ~/.bashrc` and still the same.

Comment: I tired `nano ~/.bashrc` now added a word `yay` to the comment and now it prompted me.  I always thought editing .bashrc was a sudo command because I remember it asking me to use sudo back when I had Ubuntu 16.04 and it just became a habit.